# store selected item in ram in ui tabbar objective-c

Tags: ios, uitabbar, ram

I'm new to ios. I'm uising uitabbar. I want to store in ram only currently selected viewcontroller of the secific UItabbarControllerItem is there a way to implement it?

UITabbar is loading all viewcontrollers in ram. I don't like it. I want to make it work following way: store in memory only 1 selected viewcontroller,
when user selects othe uitabbar item it loads again new viewcontroller

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Why do you want to do that do you what to run some code that is in viewdidload???

Comment: i have a problem with UIWebView, i have about 7 tabs and each one of them has UIWebView that is loading some url, it's very bad for memory. I want to reduce emory usage using only one viewcontroller at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wanna do this? IOS is responsible for managing memory, but try this.
When you load a controller you can make a loop over "controllers" property of the tabbar and put a nil value to each. Be careful, don't put your current controller = nil.

tabbar.controllers is an array with the all the controllers of the tabbar. If you are in the second one, is the tabbar.controllers[1], don't put this one to nil.

If you want to go to other controller, you have to create it an assign to the tabbar.controllers. But, which position? the array only have one position, the current controller, and almost certainly will not work tabbar buttons. It will generate an exception and your app fall.

I do not recommend you do this, but yourself

Comment: i have a problem with UIWebView, i have about 7 tabs and each one of them has UIWebView that is loading some url, it's very bad for memory. I want to reduce emory usage using only one viewcontroller at runtime